# Confused as to why my fetch method isn't sending JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Front-End, using React

```
async callAPI() {
  const data = { username: "eric", password: "password" };
  const response = await fetch("/login", {
    method: "post",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });

  console.log(response);
  const body = await response.json();

  console.log(body);

  return body;
}
```

Backend, using express

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  let userN = User.findOne(
    { username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password },
    (err, doc) => {
      console.log(doc);

      res.send({
        username: doc.username,
        password: doc.passsword,
        recipeBook: doc.recipeBook
      });
    }
  );
});
```

When I reach the line,

```
console.log(req.body)
```

In my express code, I end up getting 'undefined' so it seems that the fetch isn't actually sending the data to my backend. In my front-end, I end up getting this error,

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Why won't it send data to my back-end? Also should I be using libraries like Axios to do communication between back-end and front-end instead of the fetch api? Lastly, why does back end have different methods like "get" and "post"? How come "post" is the only method that's allowed to have a req.body, whereas "get" isn't?

Comment: What do you see in the Network Tab?

Comment: What version of Express are you using? If I'm not mistaken, Express started using automatic body parsing in 4.16.0, so if you have an earlier version you will have to use a body parser middleware.

Comment: For the last question, it is important to know how HTTP works, and what its different verbs/methods mean. [MDN has a decent listing to start from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods). For the remainder, please limit yourself to a single question in your question. It is currently too broad for a single answer. Finally, searching for that error reveals many questions on Stack Overflow. E.g., ["SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" in React App](//stackoverflow.com/q/37280274)

Comment: also don't forget to include body parser if you have not. https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json

Comment: try adding { Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* , "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" } in headers while calling api.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I didn't use something called "body-parser".

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser